# How to display "git blame" in PhpStorm after opening file by default

Tags: php, phpstorm, webstorm

How to display "git blame" after opening a file by default in PhpStorm.

**Without "right-click the left gutter, and select the Annotate option"**, 
I want to display "git blame" by default after just opening files.

Answer (score 82):

'git blame' is supported - the command is called **annotate** in PhpStorm.

1. Right-click the file
2. Choose **Git** > **Annotate**

[image: Annotate option in the context menu]

[image: Annotate result in the file]

Comment: Thanks for your advice. But I know it. Without "right-click the left gutter, and select the Annotate option", I want to display "git blame" by default after just opening files.

Comment: why `Annotate` feature is disabled, even if repo is under `Git`?

Comment: You doesn't seem to answer the question that was asked!

Comment: @Kalmar But almost anyone coming here simply wants to view git blame; as this question is the first result for the query "View git blame phpstorm" in google

Answer (score 12):

You can set a hotkey for almost anything in PHPStorm.

Click Preferences > Keymap. Search for Annotate. You can then set a hotkey to toggle Annotations in PHPStorm.

This doesn't exactly solve the problem of showing annotations when a file is opened but does eliminate the need for lots of fiddly clicking.

Comment: In recent versions of Intellij's IDEs the option is listed as `Git Blame` instead of `Annotate`. Search for that instead.

Comment: and. right now it's "Annotate with Git Blame" on PHPStorm :)

Answer (score 8):

It is possible with the [GitToolbox](https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/7499-gittoolbox) plugin. 
These settings are enabled by default i think and it also displays the blame in the status bar.

If you want to edit the settings, you go to File-> Settings-> Version Control -> GitToolbox and you can see the checkbox 'Show editor inline 'Blame''.

Answer (score 3):

It's not exactly an solution, but can help if you're tired of creating new shortcuts for every little functionality that you need.

You **right click** the file, press **G**, release, and press **N**

it's the same as pointing to the GIT, waiting for the window to popup and selecting the annotate function, only faster.

That's the way I do.

Hope it helps somebody