# How can I show annotations in PhpStorm/WebStorm search preview

Tags: php, phpstorm, webstorm, git-blame

When previewing a file in the search window, the "Annotate" (git blame) option is grayed out. Is there a way to enable this with an config option or a plugin? Searching "phpstorm show annotations in search" takes me to this unrelated question: [How to display "git blame" in PhpStorm after opening file by default](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27559063/how-to-display-git-blame-in-phpstorm-after-opening-file-by-default)

[image]

Comment: I think you need to create a feature/bug request at Jetbrains. I can recommend the git toolbox extension, but this wont work here, neither.

Answer (score 1):

No, it's not possible: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-250927. Just open the file & use Annotate there instead.

Answer (score 0):

As of at least version 2022.3.1 this is now available. It seems to work for most files.

[image]